# remove duplicates from dataframe with certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, aggregate-functions

I have the following data frame

```
my_id  field_1   field_2   field_3 ...  field_100
1         :
1         :      
1
1 
2
2
3
3
3
```

I want to keep only one row for each `my_id`, using the record with non-null, minimum `field_1`. Except looping over the entire data frame, is there an elegant way to approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
df.sort_values(['myid','field_1']).drop_duplicates(['my_id'])
```

This works because `sort_values` puts the null values last by default, and `drop_duplicates` keeps the first. So if you sort it by `field_1`, then the first value will be the lowest non-null value.

**Example:**

```
>>> df
   myid  field_1   field_2
0     1      NaN  0.832445
1     1      3.0  0.742906
2     1      2.0  0.392163
3     2      2.0  0.089412
4     2      NaN  0.815754
5     2      1.0  0.615426

>>> df.sort_values(['myid','field_1']).drop_duplicates(['myid'])
   myid  field_1   field_2
2     1      2.0  0.392163
5     2      1.0  0.615426
```

An alternative is to sort, then use `groupby` and select the `first` (but I think this is less efficient):

```
>>> df.sort_values('field_1').groupby('myid', as_index=False).first()
   myid  field_1   field_2
0     1      2.0  0.392163
1     2      1.0  0.615426
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `idxmin` since it already take care of both `NaN`(will not be considered) and `min` (will be picked)

```
df.loc[df.groupby('myid').field_1.idxmin()]
```